# How to call an action of controller in ASP.NET Core angular web application

Tags: c#, node.js, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I created an ASP.NET Core angular project. There is a default component of angular and a `HomeController` of mvc. When I run the application directly, it works fine. web page shows output of the angular component. then I look at the source code of `HomeController`, it looks like below:

```
class HomeController
{
    // ... some code here
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    // ... some code here
}
```

So far what I want to do is use a URL to call the Get method, it is not using ajax to call the action. I just put the URL to address bar of browser. the URL I use is: `/Home/Get`. but it does not work, the page still show the output of angular component.

So how to solve this problem?

Comment: If the browser responds the Angular app, you are probably using the wrong domain. Angular server runs, in development, in http:localhost:4200 (using 4200 port). Your ASP.Net app is running in another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access your controller you should make it into API path like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
class HomeController: Controller
{
    // ... some code here
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    // ... some code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. but i do not understand why it can work. i create a asp.net core project first, so url /home/get can work. then i append angular to this project. developed some components to learn some angular things. after that url home/get does not work. would you like me why ? thanks

Comment: @Frank If it work please vote up and mark my answer as accepted. Because if you are using visual studio 2019 there is an option to create a api template or angular template. Angular template by default dong have api controller so you just need to add one

Comment: I am having this same problem.  I am trying to access an API like that above but the API URL keeps rerouting to the Angular app on port 4200.